# In Unity2d I have a circle which moves by rigibody addforce. If it a child of a moving platform it deforms and the scale goes weird

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a circle that moves with rb addforce in unity 2d If i make it a child of a moving platform(to keep it on the platform when it's moving) It deforms and the local scale goes weird. I've tried only a few things and none of them fix it.

any help?

Answer (score -1):

Changing the tranform of the parent will affect the child.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao thats why I asked it as a question but you edited it , nonetheless im confused now , have a nice day .

Comment: In unity if the parrents transform is not uniform , any rotation will deform the childs local scale . Fix : make parent transform uniform for example (1,1,1).